# Android - get screen touch event

Tags: android, events, touch

I need to know when the user is using the screen over my activity, even when he is not strictly on my activity (for instance when he drawed the notification drawer, or when he is on Messenger). That is because i want my app to do something after a certain time of absence of action by the user, and such cases mess with the timer, as the activity is not paused.

I tried with dispatchTouchEvent() and onTouchEvent() but they only handle event made on my activity.

So is there a way to detect touch event made on layout that has been drawn by other app over my activity?

Answer (score 0):

You can cretae transparent overlay window by system alert. It always on top. 
Then you can handle touch event and stretching further.
[Creating a system overlay window (always on top)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481226/creating-a-system-overlay-window-always-on-top)